# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017 al ejecutar app de node vía cmd

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose, express-session

Al ejecutar mi app con node app.js por cmd queda el navegador cargando con mi localhost:8080 y me sale este error:

> (node:9492) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
> at new MongooseServerSelectionError (C:\Users\oscar\Desktop\node\proyecto\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\serverSelection.js:22:11)
> at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\oscar\Desktop\node\proyecto\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:823:32)
> at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\oscar\Desktop\node\proyecto\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:333:15)
> at Object. (C:\Users\oscar\Desktop\node\proyecto\models\user.js:4:10)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
> at Object. (C:\Users\oscar\Desktop\node\proyecto\app.js:3:12)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
> (node:9492) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
> (node:9492) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Hola Oscar, aparte del error podrías añadir tu Código de tu archivo app.js.

Comment: app.post("/sessions",function (req,res) {

    User.findOne({email:req.body.email,password:req.body.password},function (err,user) {
        req.session.user_id = user._id;
        console.log(doc);
        res.send("Hola nuevo");  
    });
});

app.listen(8080);

Comment: var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/fotos", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

Answer (score 0):

En la conexión a la base de datos prueba la url de la siguiente manera:

Tu url actual:

```
mongodb://localhost/fotos
```

Por:

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/fotos
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fotos", {
 useNewUrlParser: true, 
 useCreateIndex: true, 
 useUnifiedTopology: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

En versiones siguientes a la 17 de node (v17.x) lo único que debes hacer es cambiar localhost por 127.0.0.1.
Por ejemplo:

```
  mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1/fotos", {
 useNewUrlParser: true, 
 useCreateIndex: true, 
 useUnifiedTopology: true
});
```